# De-Referencing each element of an std::vector of pointers to objects

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector

Supposing that I have a class called `TextEntry` with some instance variables and a method `ask()` (which returns an integer).

I then create a vector of type: `std::vector<TextEntry*> d_text` (a vector of pointers of type `TextEntry`). I wish to iterate over all the elements in this vector and call the method `ask()` applied to each element. Is this the correct way to do it?

```
for (std::vector<TextEntry*>::iterator it = d_text.begin(); it != d_text.end(); ++it) {

    TextEntry* TextEntryPointer = *it; // first dereference the iterator 

    TextEntry TextEntry = *TextEntryPointer; // dereference the TextEntry pointer

    int j = TextEntry.ask();

}
```

For whatever reason this implementation is giving me an error so it would be helpful to know if the reason why is because of the above code or some other problem in the rest of my project.

Comment: "It would be helpful to know" what the error is

Comment: If it makes it easier, you can skip the deference of the pointer and just call `TextEntryPointer->ask()`

Comment: If you want to call `ask()` on each element of the vector, you should ask yourself why you are calling it on copies of said elements.

Comment: You make a copy of textEntry at the 3rd line and you call ask on this copied object. Nevertheless, your code does not seems to have an error, the problem may come from members of textEntry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wish to iterate over all the elements in this vector and call the method ask() applied to each element. Is this the correct way to do it?

Almost.

Your program doesn't call `ask` on any element pointed by `d_text` but on a copy of each pointed element.

---

> I am confused why it is a copy.

You create a variable of type `TextEntry`. You copy-initialize it from `*TextEntryPointer`. That is why there is a copy.

> Is there a way to call it on the original element?

Yes. Instead of copy-constructing a `TextEntry` variable, you could use a reference variable instead:

```
TextEntry& TextEntry = *TextEntryPointer;
```

This refers to the object pointed by the element in the vector.

Or more simply, don't create an intermediate variable at all:

```
int j = TextEntryPointer->ask();
```

Perhaps not even for the pointer:

```
int j = (*it)->ask();
```

You could simplify the loop as well:

```
for(TextEntry* ptr : d_text) {
    int j = ptr->ask();
}
```

---

> For whatever reason this implementation is giving me an error

There is a missing semicolon

> ```
> TextEntry TextEntry = *TextEntryPointer // dereference the TextEntry pointer
> ```

---

PS. Avoid naming a variable with a same identifier as a type.

Comment: Is there a way to call it on the original element I am confused why it is a copy.

Comment: @JamesDickens try (**it).ask(); or (*it)->ask();

Answer (score 1):

An example program with little bit assumption.
  Look into main function for invoking the member function.

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>

using namespace std;

class TextEntry
{
    public:

    int ask()
    {

       return 1;

    }

};

int main()
{
    vector<TextEntry*> te;

    TextEntry* te1 = new TextEntry();
    TextEntry* te2 = new TextEntry();
    TextEntry* te3 = new TextEntry();
    TextEntry* te4 = new TextEntry();

    te.push_back(te1);
    te.push_back(te2);
    te.push_back(te3);
    te.push_back(te4);

    for (std::vector<TextEntry*>::iterator it = te.begin(); it != te.end(); ++it) 
    {
        TextEntry *t = *it;
        cout<<t->ask();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are correct. But we have 2016 now, so we have c++11:

```
for (auto& text_entry_ptr: d_text)
{
    int j = text_entry_ptr->ask();
}
```

Much simpler and cleaner.